# FreeNAS - how to "Exclude from file" in Rsyncd (GUI)

Tags: linux, rsync, truenas, exclude

I am trying to set rsync tasks to Pull user profiles from 11 Windows machines running DeltaCopy Server and then configure ZFS periodic snapshot tasks for a backup solution. So far this has been working fine, although i would like to exclude certain file types like .DAT or NTUSER.DAT.

My Exclusion file resides on the local ZFS Dataset (Receiving side) and is as follows:

```
   Temp
   Temporary Internet Files
   NTUSER.DAT
   NTUSER.DAT.LOG
   *.dat
   *.tmp
   *.DAT.log
   *.ost
   *.pst
```

The command i typed under Auxiliary Parameters (Rsyncd Global Conf under services)is as follows:
exclude from = /mnt/Storage/User_Profiles/exclude.txt

Ive tried deleting the .DAT files from the receiving end and just as i start to get excited i click refresh and there they are again

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use --delete in the rsync command, such as:

```
rsync -avz --delete source destination
```

This deletes files in destination that are no longer in the source. Since you use a GUI in a NAS appliance, YMMV.